# How to walk a directory recursively returning the full path in PHP?

Tags: php, directory

I'm trying to get the behavior like the "tree" command on linux or unix systems where the function returns a list or array of directories in its full path.

Example

```
~/
~/Pictures
~/Movies
~/Downloads
~/Documents
~/Documents/work
~/Documents/important
~/Documents/bills
~/Music
~/Music/80s/
```

etc .... etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator ('.')) as $x)
{
        echo $x->getPathname (), "\n";
}
```

**Update #1:**

If you want empty directories to be listed as well, use RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator ('.'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $x)
{
    echo $x->getPathname (), "\n";
}
```

Comment: the problem with this function is that it does not return empty directories. Also is getPathname() necessary? I tried without and it seemd to work fine? Thanks again! :)

Comment: See my update. The use of getPathname () is not required, of course.

Comment: This produces dot files which is strange as I thought that flag SKIP_DOTS was the default on RecursiveDirectoryIterator?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout PHP's [Recursivedirectoryiterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). It will do what you need, and it has some nice examples.