# Recursively Search within a directory for all folder paths

Tags: php, directory-structure

I am trying to recursively search through a directory for all sub-directories within any directories of sub-directories.  Basically all folders starting at the root directory, and I need to copy a file to all folders found as well as in the main root folder.  How can I do this?

Here's what I have so far, but it needs to be recursive completely so that it gets all folders within that root, and folders within subs, and folders within that, neverending search, until there are no more folders left...

```
@copy($extendVars['dir'] . '/index.php', $real_extendpath . '/index.php');

$dh = @opendir($real_extendpath);
while (false !== ($obj = readdir($dh)))
{
    if ($obj == '.' || $obj == '..')
        continue;

    if (is_dir($real_extendpath . '/' . $obj))
        @copy($extendVars['dir'] . '/index.php', $real_extendpath . '/' . $obj . '/index.php');
}

closedir($dh);
```

Comment: You need to make a function out of this to call it recursive.

Comment: ok, but how?  I'm not seeing a way to do that.  Is there a better way to do this other than using readdir?  Isn't there like a RecursiveIterator function of some sort?  Would that be better?  If so, how to use that function is tricky for me also...

Comment: The manual is full of exmples. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#105891 - Also `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to walk a directory recursively returning the full path in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016883/how-to-walk-a-directory-recursively-returning-the-full-path-in-php)

Comment: It should be consent, that PHP example code with the `@` operator should not be posted on SO.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - do a google for "recursive function php" - that will make it clear. It's very good practise to learn how to do this, even if in your use case it is easier to use the SPL iterator.

Comment: @hakre - What's wrong with posting PHP example code with the `@` operator?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: The `@` operator is often a sign that there is no proper error and pre-condition checking done within the code. As giving examples here on SO you motivate others to execute the code on other systems. In such a case, a more defensive approach is useful, with proper error checking, useful error message so it's clear as well for the OP how others need to deal with the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursing over the filesystem for only the directories can be super-easy using the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and friends from the Standard PHP Library ([docs](http://php.net/spl)).

A basic example would look like

```
$directories = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new ParentIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory_to_iterate)), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    // Do your work here
}
```

---

For your particular needs, the `// Do your work here` could be as simple as the following snippet.

```
copy($extendedVars['dir'] . '/index.php', $directory . '/index.php');
```