# Use function recursively to list all files in dir and subdirs

Tags: php, function

I wrote down this simple function to have on an array all the files present in a dir and subdirs, but it isn't working. When I echo `$f` nothing is displaing.
Where am I going wrong?

```
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);

function scanSubDir($w_dir){
    $dir = scandir($w_dir);

    foreach($dir as $f){
        if($f != '..' || $f != '.'){
            if(is_file($w_dir.$f)){
                $list[] = $f;
            }elseif(is_dir($w_dir.$f)){
                scanSubDir($w_dir.$f);
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}

$file = scanSubDir(ROOT_DIR.'/test/');

foreach($file as $f){
    echo $f;
}
```

Comment: You can't append `$dir` and `$f`, because `$dir` is a scandir result array.

Comment: For one, you're hard-wiring the directory in your function (`$dir = scandir(ROOT_DIR.'/test/');`) - so it's only ever going to scan that directory. For another, you're not actually adding anything to $list when you make the recursive call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Recursively Search within a directory for all folder paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938680/php-recursively-search-within-a-directory-for-all-folder-paths)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your code:

```
function scanSubDir($w_dir){
    $dir = scandir($w_dir);

    $list = array(); // <-- create initially empty list of files 
    foreach($dir as $f){
        if($f != '..' || $f != '.'){
            if(is_file($dir.$f)){
                $list[] = $f;
            }elsif(is_dir($dir.$f)){
                $sublist = scanSubDir($dir.PATH_SEPARATOR.$f); // <-- include path separator! 
                $list = array_merge($list, $sublist); // <-- merge the result of the recursive call
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Note that:

- The resulting list contains only filenames, without paths. It may be ok or not ok in your case. For example, for the following directory structure:

  ```
   dir
   |_ subdir 
   |  |_ file.txt
   |  |_ file.jpg
   |_ file.txt
  ```

  the result would be: `array('file.txt', 'file.jpg', 'file.txt')`  (order of array elements may be different). 
  Note that `'file.txt'` comes twice, without path information.
- Symbolic/hard links may produce infinite recursion, resulting in stack overflow :) 
  If your directories are expected to contain links, you may want to consider this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function _scandir($dir = '.', $files = array())
{
    foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
        if(is_file($file)) {
            $files[] = $file;
        }else{
            $files = array_merge($files, _scandir($file));
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
?>

<pre>
<?php print_r(_scandir()); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Awful solution, this can literally be achieved with 3 lines of code using PHP's directory iterator.